# Hide html horizontal but not vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have an HTML textarea that is of fixed width, but variable height. I would like to set `overflow:scroll` and be able to show a vertical scrollbar, but not a horizontal one. I am not able to use `overflow:auto` due to other things specific to my situation.

I know there is no way using CSS2 to show only vertical but not horizontal scrollbars. Is there anything I can do with JavaScript to hide the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: No, using CSS2 and `overflow:scroll;` there is no way to show one bar and not the other. It's inherent in `overflow:scroll`; javascript can only do what CSS allows. However, my guess is that you *can* use overflow:auto, you just don't know how. Would you elaborate on the "other things specific to your situation"?

Answer (score 585, accepted):

You can use css like this:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: I'm seeing that as CSS3, and it doesn't work in Firefox when I test it. I also see that this is available as an IE-only property from way back in the day.

Comment: @wiliamjones - This works in firefox...do you have an example page?  Might be some other layout reason it's not working.

Comment: @william - Here's a complete example of it working, test in firefox :) http://jsfiddle.net/qpZ8k/

Comment: You're right, it does work with Firefox, it's the Prototype javascript library that isn't compatible with this attribute, which was easy enough to work around.

Is this property generally reliable across browsers?

Comment: @williamjones - Yup, it's usually the case with these things, browsers implement it, then it's a standard later as an afterthought.

Comment: Will this work with `word-wrap: break-word;` in CSS?

Answer (score 31):

Use CSS. It's easier and faster than javascript.

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Answer (score 22):

Disable horizontal scrollbar completely by adding this code.

```
body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Using `wrap=virtual` in your HTML form boxes gets rid of the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the box:

```
  <textarea name= "enquiry" rows="4" cols="30" wrap="virtual"></textarea>
```

See ***example*** here : http://jsbin.com/opube3/2 **(Tested on FF and IE)**

Answer (score 3):

```
selector{
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Working example with snippet and jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/sx8u82xp/3/

[image]

```css
.container{
  height:100vh;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>

<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>

<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>

<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;background-color:#000000">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.combobox_selector ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

sets 200px scrolldown size, `overflow-x` hides any horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

For me:

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv {
   position: relative;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow-y: auto;  <------
   overflow-x: hidden; <-----
   text-align: left;
}
```

Of course remove the arrows

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```css
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto
```