# IE 8 Overflow not rendering

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm trying to add overflow to an HTML element, and of course it works in every browser but IE.

Here is my code:

```
<div class = "twitter">
  <div class="twitter_image">
    <div class="user"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="label">
    <div class="boarder_control">
      <div class= "tweet_container">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class ="smfooter"></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
  .twitter {
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    background-color: green;
  }

  .smfooter {
    padding: 2px;
    height: 10px;
  }

  .label {
    height: 15px;
  }

  .tweet_container {
    overflow-y:auto;
  }

  .boarder_control{
    padding:5px;
  }

  .tweet {
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
  }
```

What are the best practices for using overflow with IE 8?

IE:

[image: All other browsers on earth]

All other browsers on earth:

[image: IE]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp

Note: The overflow-y property does not work properly in IE8 and earlier.

You can resolve this by using overflow: scroll;

If there is a horizontal scroll bar then you may have to hide it with another div.

Try this thread...

[Hide html horizontal but not vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594389/hide-html-horizontal-but-not-vertical-scrollbar)

Answer (score 0):

try to also assign an height to  `.tweet_container` e.g.

```
.tweet_container { height: 300px; overflow-y: auto; }
```