# Can anyone help me to remove this footer scroll bar?

Tags: responsive

Guys

I'm facing a problem on my website. Can anyone help me to remove that footer scroll bar ?

My site is "**[crazymasscouponscode](http://crazymasscouponscode.com/)**"

Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide html horizontal but not vertical scrollbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594389/hide-html-horizontal-but-not-vertical-scrollbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the horizontal scrollbar, add in the following code as CSS:

```
body {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

For your information, the next time you ask a similar question, it would be beneficial to include a screenshot or description of your problem, rather than a link to your site. Mainly, this is so we don't think you simply want pageviews, and so others can learn from this problem, regardless of what changes on your site.

Comment: Thanks it's working for me

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it worked. FYI, the solution was already on SO. In the future, search before asking. :)