# Hide scrollbar in Firefox and Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any Javascript/Jquery plugins, or css tricks are available to hide scrollbar in Firefox / Edge (Native scrollbar) ?
ie, i have to scroll the area but, the scrollbar should not be visible.

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` ?

Comment: If this were the UX SE, I'd let you know I hated it when sites did that on my odd screen sized netbook and left elements outside the margin.  Oh, and set sizes based on screen width, so stuff was off the bottom (looking at you gmail), and I couldn't scroll down to it, so I'd have to control-minus to shrink stuff.  But this is not the UX SE, so I won't tell you how much I hate it when sites do that

Comment: You can work out the width of the scrollbar, increase the scrolling element's width by the width of the scrollbar, then put it inside an `overflow: hidden` container. It's a bit messy though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide html horizontal but not vertical scrollbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594389/hide-html-horizontal-but-not-vertical-scrollbar)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<style>

   //Chrome, Safari, Opera
    body ::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }  

    //Firefox
    body { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }

    //Internet Explorer, Edge
    body { -ms-overflow-style: none; }

</style>
```

Comment: For Firefox I had to use `scrollbar-width: none`.

Comment: Dude, you just saved my day.