# Content Scrolling / Overflowing Horizontally

Tags: html, css, angular

i am Currently working on a Angular 2 Website.
I wanted to have a Landing section which covers the Full screen, a content Section, which is as large as the Content inside and a Footer at the Bottom as well as a navbar that stays always on top.

I'm more of a Backend-Developer, so CSS is not my biggest Strength.

My Current code for Testing is:

Global CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

App-Component HTML and CSS:

```
<app-home></app-home>
<header>
    Test
</header>
```

.

```
header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

And my Home-Component HTML / CSS:

```
<header></header>

<div class="content"></div>

<footer></footer>
```

.

```
header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
}

footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

The Problem i Currently have is, that all my Containers are about 10px wider that the screen. Because of this there is a Horizontal Scrollbar at the bottom.
The weird thing is that this Problem only occurs when i add the content or footer section. When i only have the header Everything is fine.
Also the Navbar stays in the correct size.

[Image of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzXN6.png)

Probalby it's just a stupid small mistake, but even with other solutions from Stack Overflow i tried it is still not working.

I appreciate all your Help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594389/hide-html-horizontal-but-not-vertical-scrollbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change width to 100% from width: 100vw for body; Like below:

```
  html, body {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100vh;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew it had to be something so small and stupid :D

Comment: Welcome, Enjoy Coding!